# Understanding keepalive between client and cockroachdb with haproxy

Tags: postgresql, haproxy, keep-alive, cockroachdb, tcp-keepalive

We are facing a problem where our client lets name it *A*. Is attempting to connect *DB* server (Cockroach) name *B* load balanced via ha-proxy

```
A < -- > haproxy < -- > B
```

Now at every, while our client A is receiving `Broken Pipe` error.

But I'm not able to understand why?

Cockroach server already has the below default value i.e 60 seconds.

```
COCKROACH_SQL_TCP_KEEP_ALIVE ## which is enabled to send for 60 second
```

Plus our haproxy config has the following setting.

```
defaults
    mode                tcp
    # Timeout values should be configured for your specific use.
    # See: https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#4-timeout%20connect
    timeout connect     10s
    timeout client      1m
    timeout server      1m
    # TCP keep-alive on client side. Server already enables them.
    option              clitcpka
```

**option              clitcpka**

So what is causing the TCP connection to drop when the keepalive is enabled on every end.

Answer (score 1):

Keepalive is what *makes* connections go away if one of the end points has died without closing the connection. Investigate in that direction.

The only time keepalive actually keeps the connection alive is in connection with an ill-configured firewall that drops idle connections.